# JavaScript - Form validation loop through specific fields

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I'm wondering, what would be a *short/good* way of performing form validation in **JavaScript** by looping through all `input-text` as well as `<select>`, however, the condition on the select is that out of the 2 selects, **ONLY** one needs to be selected.

```
<form id="daform">
<input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="text" value="" name="last" id="last" />

<select id="choice1" name="choice1">
 <option>Bye</option>
 <option>Hello</option>
</select>

<select id="choice2" name="choice2">
 <option>Bye</option>
 <option>Hello</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into,[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/element.getelementsbytagname).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)?
You can see a demo [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/).

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: I think your life will be more easier if you use jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

You really should use some javascript toolkit for help with this, but if not this might help:

```
validateSelectChoices = function(){
  return document.getElementById('choice1').selectedIndex || document.getElementById('choice2').selectedIndex;
}
```

This will check to see if one of the select boxes has the 'hello' value selected (keep in mind that dropdowns will always default to the first option in the list, in your case 'bye'.